# jQuery change selected item style on different selection

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project where I need to change the indication style of an item when another item in the same row is selected. I also need to make an overlay visible on all other items excepted the selected item.

Right now I have working code that highlights the selected item, and makes the overlay appear, but my lack of experience is causing me confusion as to how to make this work as mentioned above. Here's the code for reference.

```js
$(".prod_link").bind('click', function(){
    $(this).find("img").addClass('glow');
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".after").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.prod_thumb{height: 100px; width: 100px;}
.prod_thumb:hover{
 margin: 10px auto;
 height: 95px;
 width: 95px;
 background-color: #cd1041;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(205, 16, 65, .75); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(205, 16, 65, .75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(205, 16, 65, .75);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; /* IE10 is actually unprefixed */
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.glow {
 margin: 5px auto;
 height: 95px;
 width: 95px;
 background-color: #cd1041;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(205, 16, 65, .75); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(205, 16, 65, .75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(205, 16, 65, .75);
}
.image-container { position: relative; }
.image-container .after { position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 95px; height: 95px; display: block; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6); }
.image-container .after:hover{opacity: 0; transition: 0.3s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 image-container">
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" class="prod_link">
    <img src="img/kitchen/cookware2.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
     <div class="after" style="display: none;"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 image-container">
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" class="prod_link">
     <img src="img/kitchen/cookware3.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
      <div class="after" style="display: none;"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 image-container">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" class="prod_link">
    <img src="img/kitchen/cookware4.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
     <div class="after" style="display: none;"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 image-container">         
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" class="prod_link">
     <img src="img/kitchen/cookware5.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
     <div class="after" style="display: none;"></div>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was approaching this the wrong way in terms of my markup and my jQuery. The biggest problem was the `img` elements were nested unnecessarily deep, and the `a` elements were completely unnecessarily. When an item is clicked, a modal appears. If the user clicks a button with the class `add-item`, the clicked image has `glow` added to it, and `blur` is added to the remaining images in the same carousel. (Disregard the xajax calls in the jQuery, I remembered this post after I moved along in the project to making it more dynamic).

The correct code is below.

HTML:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row" id="row-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 thumb" id="thumb-1" data-pid="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product_modal">
            <img src="img/kitchen/dinnerware1.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 thumb" id="thumb-2" data-pid="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" >
            <img src="img/kitchen/dinnerware2.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 thumb" id="thumb-3" data-pid="3" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" >
            <img src="img/kitchen/dinnerware3.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 thumb" id="thumb-4" data-pid="4" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" >
            <img src="img/kitchen/dinnerware4.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 thumb" id="thumb-5" data-pid="5" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prod_modal" >
            <img src="img/kitchen/dinnerware5.jpg" class="img-responsive prod_thumb"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blur{
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    filter: url(../img/blur.svg#blur); /* Firefox fix */
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
    filter:progid:DXImageTranform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3'); /* IE compatibility fix */
}

.blur:hover{
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    filter: none;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0'); /* IE compatibility fix */
}
```

jQuery:

```
// add to cart btn on products
$(".add-item").bind('click', function(){
    $("div[id^='thumb-']").find('img').removeClass('glow').addClass('blur'); // remove glow from previous selection, add blur to all
    $('#thumb-' + sid).find('img').addClass('glow').removeClass('blur'); // add glow to current selection, remove blur

    var rowid = clid.split('-')[1]; // get the row number from clid
    $("#chkbox-"+ rowid).attr("src","img/checkedbox.png"); // swap empty_chkbox.png fro checkedbox.png

    // xajax_addToCart($(this).attr('data-pid'), $(this).attr('data-obj'));
});

$(".thumb").bind('click', function(e){
    sid = $(this).attr("data-pid"); // assign sid (selected id)
    clid = $(this).parent().attr('id'); // assign clid (checklist id)

    $("#product_modal").attr("data-pid", sid);

    xajax_view($(this).attr("data-pid")); // get information to populate modal
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#product_modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    // clear out selected id and checklist id
    sid = 0;
    clid = "";
});
```

If you see any other issues with my code below, please feel free to comment! I'm constantly striving to improve!